# 2 questions regarding logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

There are 2 similar questions on $\log$ that I'm unable to solve.

1. Given that $\log_a xy^2 = p$  and $\log_a x^2/y^3 = q $. Express $\log_a 1/\sqrt{xy}$ or $\log_a 1/(xy)^{1/2}$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ 
   ($a$ is the base). I was thinking along the line of using $p - q$ but I can't seem to get $y^{1/2}$. The answers are $3p+\frac{2q}7$ and $-5p-\frac q{14}$
2. Given that $\log_b(x^3y^2) = p$ and $\log_b(y/x) = q$. Express $\log_b(x^2y)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ .($b$ is the base)

Comment: Can you at least clarify your notation with brackets? Do you mean log (base a) (xy)^2 or log (base a) x(y^2)? etc. Then I'll edit it with TeX code.

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations

Comment: Do you know the basic facts about logarithms? E.g., $\log(rs)=\log r+\log s$, $\log(u^t)=t\log u$?

Comment: @John. If you put good title to your question you can attract more viewers and hence get better solutions.

Comment: OK, John, so what do you get when you apply them to $\log(xy^2)$ and to $\log(x^2/y^3)$?

Comment: $\log(x)$ + $\log(y^2)$  and $\ 2log(x)$ - $\ 3log(y)$ .But it doesnt help me with getting $\log_a 1/(xy)^{1/2}$.the problem is getting the power 1/2

Comment: Well, you can still do something with that $\log y^2$. Then you will have two equations relating the two quantities $\log x$ and $\log y$ to the two quantities $p$ and $q$. You can solve those equations to get an expression for each of the logs in terms of $p$ and $q$. Then you can use your facts about logarithms to express $\log1/(xy)^{1/2}$ in terms of $\log x$ and $\log y$, and, from there, in terms of $p$ and $q$. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try solving for $\log x$ and $\log y$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.  Then use that result to get the values you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

log(xy^2)    = log(x) + 2 log(y)  = p       Eq-1
log(x^2/y^3) = 2 log(x) -3 log(y)  = q     Eq-2

solving Eq-1  and 2  by multiply Eq-1 by -2 both sides

-2 log(x)  -4  log(y)  = -2p
 2 log(x)  -3  log(y)  =  q
----------------------------  by adding
            -7 log(y) = q-2p
               log(y) = (2p - q)/7
now solve for log(x)  the same way
              log(x)  =(3p + 2q)/7

log(1/(xy)^1/2)) = 0 - 1/2(log(x)+log(y)   = -1/2 log(x) -1/2 log(y0
we know log(x) and log(y) in term of p and q
log(1/(xy)^1/2)) = -1/2(3p +2q)/7 -1/2(2p - q)/7  = -5p/14 -q/14
I hope that help

Comment: It would help even more if people could read it. Please take the time to follow up the help links to learn more about formatting mathematics on this website.